# Incompatible data types while ALTER table in HSQL with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, hsqldb

How fix next error?

ERROR SchemaExport:484 - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table CATEGORY_RELATIONS add constraint FK2bn4xlg661b5xbx2qnwi1aqv0 foreign key (CATEGORY_RELATIONS_PARENT_ID) references CATEGORY
ERROR SchemaExport:485 - incompatible data types in combination in statement [alter table CATEGORY_RELATIONS add constraint FK2bn4xlg661b5xbx2qnwi1aqv0 foreign key (CATEGORY_RELATIONS_PARENT_ID) references CATEGORY]

**hibernate.version** 5.0.7.Final

**hsqldb.version** 2.3.3

Property, used for session factory

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

Category

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY",
        indexes = {
                @Index(name = "CATEGORY_NAME_INDEX",
                        columnList = "CATEGORY_NAME")})
public class Category extends JsonNamedModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_IMAGE")
    private String image;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_CATEGORY_ID", referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_ID")})
    private Category parent;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Category> children;//...
}
```

CategoryRelations

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS")
@IdClass(CategoryRelations.CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey.class)
public class CategoryRelations implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_CATEGORY_ID")
    private String categoryId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_RELATIONS_PARENT_ID")
    private String parentId;

    @Entity
    @IdClass(CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey.class)
    public static class CategoryRelationsPrimaryKey implements Serializable {
        private long categoryId;
        private long parentId;
    }//...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's complaining because your types don't match up. In `CATEGORY_RELATIONS` you have the key types as `String` but in `CATEGORY` you have the primary key as an `int`. While in actual practice you might only store integer data in both fields, the DB engine can't prove that. There's nothing stopping somebody from putting a non-integer in `CATEGORY_RELATIONS.categoryId` and making it so the FK could never be satisfied.

Try changing `CATEGORY_RELATIONS.categoryId` to an int.

And now that I look at it, your PK class shows them as longs. Try switching all of the types in your `CategoryRelations` object (and possibly the `CATEGORY_RELATIONS` table) to all be the same types.